# ObjectId() is being treated as a string literal instead of a function call in echo of bash script

Tags: bash, mongo-shell

I'm using a Mongo shell client to migrate some data in the database. But its `ObjectId()` is getting treated as string literal.

```
mongo_command="db.getSiblingDB('${MONGO_DB}').${PARTNER_BRANCHES_COLLECTION}.insertOne({partner_id: ObjectId('${partner_id}'), name: '${branch_name}'});"
echo "${mongo_command}"
```

Error:

```
db.getSiblingDB('test-db').partner_branches.insertOne({partner_id: ObjectId('

646baf35c03b676bec645da3'), name: 'John'});
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break :
```

I tried using backslashes but still same behaviour is happening

```
partner_id=646baf35c03b676bec645da3
partner_object_id="ObjectId(\"${partner_id}\")"
echo "${partner_object_id}"
```

Edit:

As pointed by @Barmar `$partner_id` starts with a new line. Can you guys give me something to concatenate

Comment: Better use `bash -x script.sh` to **debug**, then try to figure out the issue, and if you get stuck, post the output of the debug by editing your original post

Comment: `$partner_id` begins with a newline.